# how to make a checkbox always checked and retrieve their values in android

Tags: android, checkbox

i have create an app in which i am reading some file data,n represent it in `listview` with `checkbox` with `CustomAdapter`.it is working fine,but i want that all the `checkbox` visible in checked state and user can uncheck the `checkbox if` want and on backpress,he get the checked data.
**AdapterClass**

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            // tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(list1.get(position));
            // tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);

            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, true));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;

        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {

            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
              notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

        }
    }
```

**OnBackPress**

```
StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++)

            {
                if (ma.mCheckStates.get(j) == true) {
                    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(list1.get(j)
                            .toString(), "\n");
                    String first = st1.nextToken();
                    String second = st1.nextToken();
                    phno0.add(second.toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append(list1.get(j).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                            + list1.get(j).toString());
                }

            }

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("extermal_name", phno0);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

            finish();
            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


 }
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:ems="20"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#0082e6" />



    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:checked="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you want to set checkbox always checked?

Comment: yes i want all checkbox prechecked,and want to retrieve their values too.

Comment: what is mCheckStates ? please show code

Comment: add your getCount() code to get what array or list your are using, if your using Object class then add property boolean isSeleted and check inside getView()

Comment: @   Rohan Pawar can you tell me with an example,becoz i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

just put below line in your row layout file where you are taking checkbox:

```
android:checked="true"
```

then for retrive its value, just use;

`checkbox.gettext();` return string value.

and for retrive it is checked or not:

`checkbox.isChecked();` which is return boolean value.

Comment: for taking checked values,i used ma.mCheckStates.get(j) == true onbackpress() bt it returning null

Comment: u can see it,i post it

Comment: i just use your code and seen in graphical layout of xml file and it is showing checked.. i think problem can be in adapter code.. try to remove checkbox code part for set check n all.

Comment: can you give your full code. so i can check by my side also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and implement this logic according to your requirement.

```
int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

String checked = "";

String unchecked = "";
SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();

for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++)
{

     if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
     {
         checked += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
     }
     else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
     {
         unchecked+= myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge, I recommend store in SharedPreferences but you can also use database table.